# Embedded Youtube not autoplaying video in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, youtube-api

I am trying to embed a youtube video in a UIWebView and have it autoplay. Apparently this does not work. Is this related to:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html

or is it some kind of bug?

Here is my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.ontouchmove=function(e){ e.preventDefault(); };

            </script>
        </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;" bgcolor="#000000">
        <!-- 1. The <div> tag will contain the <iframe> (and video player) -->
        <div id="player" style="text-align:center;"></div>

        <script>
            // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
            //    after the API code downloads.
            var player;
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                                       height: '400',
                                       width: '768',
                                       videoId: 'HYlD0KXujAk',
                                       playerVars: {'autoplay' : 1},
                                       events: {
                                       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                       }
                                       });
            }


            // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
            //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
            //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
            var done = false;
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            }
            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you resolved this ?

Answer (score -1):

No this is no bug, this is default behavior. `UIWebView` will not play anything automatically without user intervention, except if you set `UIWebView`'s `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property to `NO` (it's `YES` by default) yourself. Then it will work.

Comment: I tried setting the property to NO but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: No! I've said it's no by default! You need to set it to YES! :P

Comment: The default value is YES btw: in the code you can see:  // iPhone and iPad Safari both default to YES

Comment: You have to set allowsInlineMediaPlayback to YES, and mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO.